# Setup Project Deployment of a Windows Forms App : Image Path Error (itextsharp)

Tags: c#, windows, forms, pdf, itext

My Windows Form is running perfectly in Build and Release Mode. I created one pdf file on Button Click. But when I created setup file then the pdf file is generated with errors. If i remove the image from my project then everything is going smooth. I placed my image in release folder and path for the image is :

```
string exeFile = (new 
Uri(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase)).AbsolutePath;
string exeDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(exeFile);
string fullPath = Path.Combine(exeDir, "header.jpg");
iTextSharp.text.Image jpg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(fullPath);
document.Add(jpg);
```

i used itextsharp library for creating the pdf

Github Link : https://github.com/loveleenkaurnancy/WindowsFormsApp1

Snapshot

[image: Click here : Snapshot]

Comment: What is the value for `fullPath`? have you debugged your code?

Comment: Full Path Value : "C:\\Users\\loveleen\\source\\repos\\WindowsFormsApp1\\WindowsFormsApp1\\bin\\Debug\\header.jpg"

Comment: And what is the error message you are getting? is that related to path?

Comment: i attached the snapshot... i am not able to open the pdf